# How do I increase the voltage gain of a Common Emitter + Common Collector without distortion in Vo?

Tags: amplifier, common-emitter, common-collector

[image]

I started with R1 and R2 half of what they were now, and with R_C = 5k. This had a gain of about 11, I managed to increase that by increasing R_C, but it seems to be plateauing when I start to get close to a gain of 30, and also the Vo waveform is distorted/clipped, which I want to avoid. I need a gain of at least 50.

Comment: You will need to adjust your bias appropriately. Is there a reason why you're operating this amplifier without feedback?

Comment: How do I adjust my bias to meet the requirements? No particular reason for operating without feedback

Comment: I don't see any common emitter stages here. Both the transistor have a resistor between the emitter and ground.

Comment: @TurboAverage419 You'd need to adjust the resistors to set the DC operating point further away from saturating the output. Feedback is a good way to establish that DC bias, if you have enough loop gain to make it work effectively.

Comment: Try this https://tinyurl.com/yhwajs2w negative feedback requires some Rfb/Rin ratio and expect 50% of that for gain when the base is pulled down and pullup the collector to prevent saturation, but not too much as that reduces gain.. Then feedback from the emitter follower since it’s there.

Comment: @TurboAverage419 Is there some requirement that you use a CE stage followed by a CC stage, as shown, and a supply rail of 15 V? Or... what actually are the requirements? What about the impact of temperature or part variations? How much distortion is allowed (because a gain of 50 is going to be hard to achieve with low distortion and only one voltage gain stage to work with.)

Comment: @jonk I actually made a mistake, Vcc needs to be 10V. The requirement is a maximum of 3 stages of any amplifiers. There are no temperature requirements.

Comment: @TurboAverage419 Is there some need for a CC stage? What's the output load? What's the input source impedance that drives the circuit? Does the bandwidth matter? Or is it just a simulation problem?

Comment: Gain is not the only spec, you shud be given a spec for impedance ratio out/in and % 2nd harmonic or % distortion and max Vout pp